# OpenCV, divide object into parts

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have the following image:[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6NhNcM1nZznQXVUZ01qS0Q3YTA/edit?usp=sharing].

Is there a function in OpenCV (preferably Python) that can say that the objects in this picture can be divided into parts. For example, the first object consists of two segments (or two lines), the third one of three (or four).

If OpenCV doesn't have such a thing, it'd be great to know about such an algorithm/function anywhere.

Comment: OpenCV Hough Line Transform may be help you http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved by skeletonizing the image and then using [HoughlinesP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlinesp#houghlinesp).
[Scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org) has a good skeletonization method.
It is straight forward to find the 14 lines segments as shown below.
Finally you will need to go through and find which sets of lines intersect to see which belong together.

[image: result]

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from skimage import morphology
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread("objects.png")
dst = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

dst = 1 - dst / 255
dst = morphology.skeletonize(dst).astype(np.uint8)

objs = 255 * dst

#cv2.HoughLinesP(image, rho, theta, threshold[, lines[, minLineLength[, maxLineGap]]])
rho = 1
theta = math.pi / 180
threshold = 1
minLineLength = 3
maxLineGap = 5

lines = np.ndarray([1, 1, 4, 4])
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dst, rho, theta, threshold, lines, minLineLength, maxLineGap)

lineColor = (0, 255, 0)  # red

for line in lines[0]:
        #print line
        cv2.line(im, (line[0], line[1]), (line[2], line[3]), lineColor, 1, 8)

#
#   Now you need to go through lines and find those that intersect
#   You will notice that some lines have small gaps where they should
#   join to a perpendicular line. Before find intersections you would 
#   need to make each line longer (just by adjusting the numbers in lines)
#   to get around this problem.
#

cv2.imshow('Objects', objs)
cv2.imshow('Lines', im)
cv2.imwrite('lines.png', im)

cv2.waitKey() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I have a problem executing that code. I've searched really a lot, but little information found:
`code`
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\opencv-2.4.7\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3737
dst = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: ..\..\..\opencv-2.4.7\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4
I've tried to replace cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY but the result was the same

Comment: S0unds like your image might be already single channel, try leaving out the `cv2.cvtColor()`, i.e set `dst = im`